# About Merging One Texture with Another Texture which has Transparent Background

Tags: texturing, node-editor

First of all, i want to explain what i am on. 
To test, i prepared a box with a material (picture 1) and a text with transparent background(picture 2) using nodes.

Picture1, the box

[image]

Picture2 and 3, alpha/opacity map to create text with transparent background and node setting for it

[image]
[image]

1. Question: Is there any node option to add text texture on box's burlap texture without affecting it...like in photoshop: text layer on another layer.
2. Question: i was tryig it with MixRGB node but all options on it changes the textures as in picture 4. Then i wanted to render it to see what it looks like. But then text doesn't seem in rendered window as in picture 5. Why does that happen ?

Picture 4, when i try it with MixRGB node and node settings for it:
[image]
[image]

Picture 5, Text doesn't appear in rendered window:
[image]

Comment: These are called *Decals*, you will find some setups for them online under this term. Your problem in pic.5 is probably the shader output going into color input (green to yellow). You want to connect green with only other greens.

Comment: This is alittle different than i was looking for. But thank you for sharing it. it seems like a good method i can use on my next projects. And i noticed about that green-yellow output-input mistake after you mentioned. That is why it doesn't appear in rendered window. it does now:)

Answer (score 2):

Plug the Alpha socket in the image node into the Mix Factor of the Mix Node there instead of the Color socket.

Comment: i tried it with alpha socket in image node into factor of Mix Node (https://prnt.sc/ghqztb), this is the result (https://prnt.sc/ghqzke). Then i tried it with color socket in image node into Mix Node(https://prnt.sc/ghr04s), it seemed working (https://prnt.sc/ghr00s). No idea how, though.